# How to use between in regex function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a field (column in Oracle) called X that has values like "a1b2c3", "abc", "1ab", "123", "156"

I wrote a sql query that returns only the X that holds pure numerical values with no letters; from the example above would be 123 and 156.

Query written using Oracle syntax:

```
select X from where REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```

Result:

```
123, 156
```

Additionally I need to write a query to get the value between 100 and 150.

How could I write such a query in Oracle? Something like below:

```
select X from where REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$') between 100 and 150
```

Comment: Can there be more than 3 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`regexp_like()` is a condition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501), so you can't compare it with anything. You can use [the `regexp_substr()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm) instead:

```
where regexp_substr(x, '^[[:digit:]]+$') between 100 and 150
```

The value returned by the function is either null or a string of digits that can be (implicitly) converted to a number for comparison.

Demo with your sample data:

```
with your_table (x) as (
  select 'a1b2c3' from dual
  union all select 'abc' from dual
  union all select '1ab' from dual
  union all select '123' from dual
  union all select '156' from dual
)
select x from your_table
where regexp_substr(x, '^[[:digit:]]+$') between 100 and 150;

X     
------
123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_number (p_string IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN INT
IS
   v_new_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_new_num := TO_NUMBER(p_string);
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
   RETURN 0;
END is_number;
```

then use this in query

```
select X from where is_number(X)=1 and TO_Number(X) between 100 and 150
```

Comment: Why not return the parsed number from the function or `NULL` on an error?

Comment: function is used to check if value is number or not if it is numeric then returns 1 else it will return 0

Comment: There's no guarantee your function call will be evaluated first here either, so this is still likely to get ORA-01722. With MTO's suggestion it would be OK though.

Comment: I know what it does but you could simplify it to: `CREATE FUNCTION check_number (p_string IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS BEGIN RETURN TO_NUMBER(p_string); EXCEPTION WHEN VALUE_ERROR  THEN RETURN NULL; END check_number;` and just use that in the `BETWEEN` filter. As @AlexPoole noted you will get an ORA-01722 if the `TO_NUMBER` check is performed before the `IS_NUMBER` check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
with tbl(X) as
(select 'a1b2c3' from dual union all select
'abc' from dual union all select
'123' from dual union all select
'156' from dual )
select * from (
   select * from tbl where
     REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$') 
               ) t
where x between 100 and 150
```

Comment: This will also get ORA-01722 if the (implicit) to_number is evaluated before the `regexp_like()`. Try it with a table, not a CTE.

Comment: Oh. let me try.

Comment: You are right! CTE behavior is more casual it seems. Editing my answer back to previous using subquery. Anyways it is moot now because of your answer.

Comment: Actually I get the same with your original query too; I guess the predicate is being pushed into the subquery, unhelpfully. Depends what mood the optimiser is in I suppose *8-)